# Order By and accented chars

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, sorting

In a Google Sheet, if we have a column with accented character strings, the sort order of menu option "Data -> Order sheet by column" correctly ignores the accents (ordered column A in image)

I would like to achieve the same result, using Query or similar function.

IF cell B1 in image is `=Query(A1:A4;"SELECT * ORDER BY A")`
the strings begining with accented chars are ordered last.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer in StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46651263/query-in-combination-with-importrange-sorts-accented-values-incorrectly

It's enough to wrap the Query with SORT() function

=Sort(*Query(xxxxx)*)

Of course, in the simple example above, use instead =Sort(A1:A4)...

Comment: And with headers?